# mdg:geolocation - App asks for general location permission but also for "http://meteor.local"

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, meteor, geolocation

Unfortunately when I deploy an iOS App, the app asks for general permission (as it should) but also afterwards for "http://meteor.local" as it is a webview.
Is there any way to bypass this second prompt or is this a "problem" you always have to deal with?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running into the same issue as you. Currently I am using Meteor 1.3 Beta 3. Try to install https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation. Run:
meteor add cordova:cordova-plugin-geolocation@2.1.0

This fixed the issue for me.